# have a screen which has checkboxes and notes, the notes are left aligned under the div and the checkboxes are right aligned

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Issue: have a screen which has check-boxes and notes, the notes are left aligned under the div and the check-boxes are right aligned.

```
<div id="ScreenData">
<div class="Title">
<div class="pNotes" data-lnotes="1" style="position:relative;">
<div class="laDiv" style="position: relative; display: block;">
<div class="divMgn ntCnt">07/24/2012 08:42 AM</div>
<div class="noteDiv" style="position:relative">
<div> Text1  </div>
<div> Text2  </div>
<div> Text3  </div>
<div>     </div>
<div> Text4  </div>
<div> Text5  </div>
<div>     </div>
<div> Text6  </div>
<div> Text7  </div>
<div align="right">
<input type="button" value="No Data" disabled="disabled">
<input id="chk_note" class="chk_note" type="checkbox" value="44344343434123"  name="chk_note">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How to get the notes captured on the left as soon as the corresponding right check-box is checked?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pole till button is not selected. As soon as button is selected, fetch the case notes.

```
while(!Driver.FindelementByXPath("Xpath for the button which would be selected").Selected)
{
Thread.Sleep(1000); //Wait till button is selected
}
string caseNotes =  Driver.FindElementByXPath("xoath for case notes textfield").Text;
```

Comment: if you could tell me where it's failing, I will be able to help you more precisely. Since, you are using Java, it might be possible, that above code might not work exactly as it is. A few changes would be required